# Microsoft Access 2013 GROUP BY Syntax Error

Tags: sql, ms-access, group-by

I am using Microsoft Access 2013, and I am trying to group the data stored in my Part table, by the Class it is stored in. I have got this query created:

```
SELECT Part.PartNum, Part.Description, Part.OnHand, Part.Class, Part.Warehouse, Part.Price
FROM Part
GROUP BY Part.Class
ORDER BY Part.PartNum;
```

The above SQL Code gives an error with Microsoft Access: "Your query does not include the specified expression 'PartNum' as part of an aggregate function". I am not sure what I am doing wrong... Should I create an extra column for the grouping?

Here is what my Part table look
[image: Part Table]

Comment: You should read about grouping and what that means. You can't just group by a column and select also others. You need to aggregate them

Comment: Drag all the fields in the select to be part of your group by... that will work.  Now do you want the average part price or the min? max?  remove it and add the min/max/avg... repeat for each field.   Are you sure you don't want to `order by part.class, part.partnum` instead though? (first by class then by part number)

Comment: I don't think you want to Group in your query at all since there's no aggregate function (Count, SUM, Min, Max...). The report will do your Grouping, sorting and create your Totals.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why do you want to `GROUP BY` `part.class`? How do you anticipate the DB will `GROUP BY` `part.class` and somehow show you `part.partnum` in the same resultset?

Answer (score 0):

I think you don’t understand the purpose of grouping.
When you group something, you have to use only grouped and aggregated columns in the select statement.
For instance, the right query could be the following:

```
SELECT Part.PartNum, SUM(Part.Price)
FROM Part
GROUP BY Part.Class, Part.Description, Part.OnHand, Part.Class, Part.Warehouse
ORDER BY Part.PartNum;
```

However, I there’s no any aggregated function in your select. Describe your task clearly.